# Getting Django Tables2 to work

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get django_tables2 to work, but I keep getting an error. I already have it installed and it's already in my settings.

models.py

```
class Schedules(models.Model):
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=COURSE_NAME_CHOICES, default='a-plus')
    location = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=LOCATION_CHOICES, default='south_plainfield')
    room = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=ROOM_CHOICES, default='A')
    start_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, default=datetime.date.today)
    start_time = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=START_TIME_CHOICES, default='eight-thirty am')
    end_time = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=END_TIME_CHOICES, default='eight-thirty am')
    instructor = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=INSTRUCTOR_CHOICES, default='adewale')
    total_hours = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=TOTAL_HOURS_CHOICES, default='six')
    hours_per_class = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=HOURS_PER_CLASS_CHOICES, default='four_and_half')
    frequency = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    interval = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=INTERVAL_CHOICES, default='1 day')
    initiated_by = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    schedule_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def save(self, flag=True, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Schedules, self).save()
        if flag:
            self.schedule_id = self.id + 10000
            self.save(flag=False, *args, **kwargs)
```

tables.py

```
import django_tables2 as tables
from schedule.models import Schedules

class ScheduleTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Schedules
```

views.py

```
from schedule.models import Schedules
from schedule.tables import ScheduleTable

def search_Schedule(request):
    context_dict = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        query = request.POST['course_name_search']
        results = Schedules.objects.filter(course_name=query)
        table = ScheduleTable(results)
        if query:
            context_dict['table'] = table
        else:
            context_dict['no_results'] = query
    return render(request, "schedule/search_schedule.html", context_dict)
```

search_schedule.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load django_tables2 %}

{% block main_content %}
<form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="course_name_search">Course Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="course_name_search" id="course_name_search">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<div id="result_panel">
    {% if no_results %}
        No results returned for <q>{{ no_results }}</q>
    {% else %}
        {% render_table table %}
    {% endif %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

The error I'm getting is 'ValueError at /schedule/search_schedule/: Expected table or queryset, not str.' I'm pretty sure I followed the steps to the letter. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Here's the traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/schedule/search_schedule/

Django Version: 1.10
Python Version: 3.6.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'registration',
 'django_countries',
 'localflavor',
 'django_tables2',
 'avtechpassport',
 'students',
 'billing',
 'timesheet',
 'wai_wdp',
 'jobs',
 'schedule']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /home/jerry22/PycharmProjects/avtechpassport_proj1/templates/schedule/search_schedule.html, error at line 38
   Expected table or queryset, not str   28 :     <form method="post" action="">
   29 :         {% csrf_token %}
   30 :         <label for="course_name_search">Course Name:</label>
   31 :         <input type="text" name="course_name_search" id="course_name_search">
   32 :         <input type="submit" name="submit">
   33 :     </form>
   34 :     <div id="result_panel">
   35 :         {% if no_results %}
   36 :             No results returned for <q>{{ no_results }}</q>
   37 :         {% else %}
   38 :              {% render_table table %} 
   39 :         {% endif %}
   40 :     </div>
   41 : {% endblock %}

Traceback:

File "/home/jerry22/.virtualenvs/jerry_avtechpassport_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/jerry22/.virtualenvs/jerry_avtechpassport_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/jerry22/.virtualenvs/jerry_avtechpassport_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/jerry22/PycharmProjects/avtechpassport_proj1/schedule/views.py" in search_Schedule
  81.     return render(request, "schedule/search_schedule.html", context_dict)

File "/home/jerry22/.virtualenvs/jerry_avtechpassport_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  30.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "/home/jerry22/.virtualenvs/jerry_avtechpassport_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  68.     return template.render(context, request)

File "/home/jerry22/.virtualenvs/jerry_avtechpassport_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/home/jerry22/.virtualenvs/jerry_avtechpassport_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  208.                     return self._render(context)

File "/home/jerry22/.virtualenvs/jerry_avtechpassport_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/jerry22/.virtualenvs/jerry_avtechpassport_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/jerry22/.virtualenvs/jerry_avtechpassport_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/jerry22/.virtualenvs/jerry_avtechpassport_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  174.         return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/home/jerry22/.virtualenvs/jerry_avtechpassport_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/jerry22/.virtualenvs/jerry_avtechpassport_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/jerry22/.virtualenvs/jerry_avtechpassport_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/jerry22/.virtualenvs/jerry_avtechpassport_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  70.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/jerry22/.virtualenvs/jerry_avtechpassport_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/jerry22/.virtualenvs/jerry_avtechpassport_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/jerry22/.virtualenvs/jerry_avtechpassport_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  323.                 return nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/jerry22/.virtualenvs/jerry_avtechpassport_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/jerry22/.virtualenvs/jerry_avtechpassport_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/jerry22/.virtualenvs/jerry_avtechpassport_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_tables2/templatetags/django_tables2.py" in render
  132.             raise ValueError('Expected table or queryset, not {}'.format(klass))

Exception Type: ValueError at /schedule/search_schedule/
    Exception Value: Expected table or queryset, not str
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a `GET` request, `{% if no_results %}` will evaluate to False, so Django tries to render a non-existent table in the `{% else %}` block.

You could do something like this instead.

```
{% if table %}
    {% render_table table %}
{% else %}
    {% if no_results %}
      No results returned for <q>{{ no_results }}</q>
    {% else %}
      Please enter a search
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```